# how to custom 500 page in node.js

Tags: node.js

I use express in node.js,and i want to custom 404 and 500 error page.

i write the code like below：

```
// Handle 404
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.send('404: Page not Found', 404);
});

// Handle 500
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
    res.send('500: Internal Server Error', 500);
    console.log(error);
});
```

it's right if 404 or error in background,but when there is a error in ejs(in a view),eg null or undefined ,it will show the detail error info..

such as:

```
Express
500 ReferenceError: 
at eval (eval at (D:\node_workspace\study\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:237:14), :29:1117)
at eval (eval at (D:\node_workspace\study\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:237:14), :29:1593)
```

etc..

i really don't want to show such error page to users.. so,how can i config to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use something like this

```
 if (app.settings.env === 'production') {
    app.error(function(err, req, res) {
        res.render('500.jade', {
           status: 500,
           locals: {
              error: error
           }
        });
    });
 }
```

And then set the custom message in the jade file like:

```
h2 Error
p Something went wrong with the application.
h3 Error Details
pre #{error}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks. i found `app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));` ,so i hide them.

Comment: You should mark the answer accepted if it serves your purpose. So that others can also check the same.